# How to analyse complexity of an Algorithm that contains hidden loops made by external function or method?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, data-structures

First of all, I would like to apologize in case my title is not concise as it should be, but my point is, if you take a look at the following code which is selection sort algorithm, it's obvious for someone to analyze its complexity.

```
module.exports = function (arr) {
 var temp;
 for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var iTh = i;        
    for (var j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
        if (arr[j] < arr[iTh]) {                
            iTh = j;                
        }
    }
    temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[iTh];
    arr[iTh] = temp;
 }
 return arr;
}
```

But what if an algorithm contains hidden loops which are provided by particular language's functions or methods. For instance these two functions are both reversing a string, and they have JavaScript methods which have complexity behind them too.

**So! How can someone analyze the complexity of these two and pick the optimal one? Or they don't qualify to be algorithms?**

**First Reverse**

```
exports.reverse1 = function (str) {
 if (str == undefined || str.length) {
    return 0;
 }
 let collector = [];
 for (var i = str.length; i >= 0; i--) {        
    collector.push(str.charAt(i));
 }
 return collector.join("");
}
```

**Second Reverse**

```
exports.reverse2 = function (str) {
 if (str == undefined || str === "") {
    return 0;
 }
 return str.split("").reverse().join("");
}
```

Comment: you can use [this to test js performance](https://jsperf.com/)

Comment: If you want to be really fancy: benchmark each method using strings of varied lengths, and then graph the runtime vs. length and take a look at the overall shape to estimate complexity.

Comment: You may be interested in the ["cyclomatic complexity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the function

Comment: Thank you @gyre for new info, is there any tool you can recommend for collecting runtime apart from Chrome DevTools or browsers in general?

Comment: Try [Benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com). Very high quality performance-measurement library.